# Documentation for SetIsQuiz method for Google forms (Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

While using the Apps Script for forms, came across this method through autocomplete. It's for instances of the Form class.

```
 form.setIsQuiz(enabled);
```

Tried looking through the documentation on what this does: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/ but can't seem to find it. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It's a procedure to set the for into a quiz mode or not so that the form can be used to assign points and add explanations to answers [See Here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7032287?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks! Nice to know